# How to export ONLY selected records in django admin?

Tags: django, csv, export

I am using the https://github.com/bendavis78/django-admin-csv to export records to csv. But it will download all records even though I select only a few.

```
from admin_csv import CSVMixin

class MyModelAdmin(CSVMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
csv_fields = list_display + ['qux']
```

Here is the admin.py file

```
from functools import update_wrapper

from django.contrib.admin.utils import label_for_field


class CSVMixin(object):
    """
    Adds a CSV export action to an admin view.
    """

    change_list_template = "admin/change_list_csv.html"

    # This is the maximum number of records that will be written.
    # Exporting massive numbers of records should be done asynchronously.
    csv_record_limit = None
    csv_fields = []
    csv_headers = {}

    def get_csv_fields(self, request):
        return self.csv_fields or self.list_display

    def get_urls(self):
        from django.conf.urls import url

        def wrap(view):
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
            return update_wrapper(wrapper, view)

        opts = self.model._meta
        urlname = '{0.app_label}_{0.model_name}_csvdownload'.format(opts)
        urlpatterns = [
            url('^csv/$', wrap(self.csv_export), name=urlname)
        ]
        return urlpatterns + super(CSVMixin, self).get_urls()

    def get_csv_filename(self, request):
        return unicode(self.model._meta.verbose_name_plural)

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        context = {
            'querystring': request.GET.urlencode()
        }
        context.update(extra_context or {})
        return super(CSVMixin, self).changelist_view(request, context)

    def csv_header_for_field(self, field_name):
        if self.headers.get(field_name):
            return self.headers[field_name]
        return label_for_field(field_name, self.model, self)

    def csv_export(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        import csv
        from django.http import HttpResponse

        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = (
            'attachment; filename={0}.csv'.format(
                self.get_csv_filename(request)))
        fields = list(self.get_csv_fields(request))
        writer = csv.DictWriter(response, fields)

        # Write header row.
        headers = dict((f, self.csv_header_for_field(f)) for f in fields)
        writer.writerow(headers)

        # Get the queryset using the changelist
        cl_response = self.changelist_view(request)
        cl = cl_response.context_data.get('cl')
        queryset = cl.get_queryset(request)

        # Write records.
        if self.csv_record_limit:
            queryset = queryset[:self.csv_record_limit]
        for r in queryset:
            data = {}
            for name in fields:
                if hasattr(r, name):
                    data[name] = getattr(r, name)
                elif hasattr(self, name):
                    data[name] = getattr(self, name)(r)
                else:
                    raise ValueError('Unknown field: {}'.format(name))

                if callable(data[name]):
                    data[name] = data[name]()
            writer.writerow(data)
        return response

    csv_export.short_description = \
        'Exported selected %(verbose_name_plural)s as CSV'
```

Here is the change_list_csv.html.

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load admin_urls %}

{% block object-tools-items %}
  {{ block.super }}
  <li>
      {% url cl.opts|admin_urlname:'csvdownload' as download_url %}
      <a href="{{ download_url }}{% if querystring %}?{{ querystring }}{% endif %}" class="link">Download CSV</a>
  </li>
{% endblock %}
```

The file looks simple but can't figure out what to change to only export the selected rows.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your "opts = self.model._meta". When I export to csv using a custom admin action, I use this: opts = queryset.model._meta, and the admin queryset does the limiting for me. The structure of your code is very different from mine so I don't know how you need to get the equivalent to the "queryset", but I think that is what is missing or not functioning correctly.